# WebApp.Start System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, console-application

from [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

`System.NullReferenceException`: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

example not work:

```
<code>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
</code>
```

Comment: error at line **using (WebApp.Start(url))**

Comment: At which port your application is running? if port 8080 already assign to another application, so this may cause an error

Comment: This question should not be closed. Linking to an answer with a million solutions is not helpful for this question. You may aswell link to Google.

Comment: @Faraz, i did try any free ports and run visual studio as admin rights